# Can I use angularJS call api GET without passing a $scope

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2, restful-url

Here is my service.js:

```
app.service('myService',['$http',function($http){
    this.getSomething = function($scope){
        return $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: "...",
            headers: {...}
        }).success(function(response){
           $scope.items = response;
        }).error(function(response){
            ...
        });
    }
}]);
```

Here is my controller.js:

```
app.controller('myController',['$scope','myService',function($scope,myService){
    $scope.items = {};
    myService.getSomething($scope);
}]);
```

But I am wondering is there another way to use web api get without passing the '$scope' to the function in the service? For example like this (I tried this but not work):

```
...
this.getSomething = function(){
    return $http({
        ...
    }).success(function(response){
        return response;
    }).error ...
        ...
}
```

then in the controller:

```
...
$scope.items = myService.getSomething();
```

Comment: I suggest you use `then` instead of `success` function. see this http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/05/28/angularjs-promises/ and https://www.peterbe.com/plog/promises-with-$http

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the `$http` services without it being in a controller.
You can put the http calls in a Service or a Factory.

Example

```
app.service('MyHttpService', function($http) {
  this.getData = function(id) {
    $http.get(<URL>, <PARAMS>).then(function(success) {
      return success;
    }, function(err) {
      return err;
    });
  }
});

// In you Controller

app.controller('MyCtrl', function(MyHttpService){
  $scope.data = getData .getData();
})
```

This is a just a simple example you can make this MyHttpService more  robust by return a promise and not the data directly;

Answer (score 0):

Yes, moving forward, it's best not to use $scope in general, but you definitely don't need to pass it along to the service. This is typically how I model my services/controllers.

***Service:***

```
//Using es6 syntax
this.getData() {
    return $http.get('/api/')
        .then(({data}) => data)
        .catch(({data}) => console.log('FAILED: ', data.message));
}

//es5
this.getData() {
    return $http.get('/api/')
        .then(function(res) {
          return res.data
        })
        .catch(function(res) {
           console.log('FAILED: ', res.data.message));
        });
}
```

***Controller:***

```
//es6
apiService.getData()
  .then(data => this.data = data);

//es5
apiService.getData()
  .then(function(data){
    this.data = data;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be passing $scope to the service. $scope is used in the controller to bind to the view.

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, service) {

   $scope.items = service.getItems();

});

app.service('service', function() {

  this.getItems() {
    return $http.get('/api/items')
    .then(function(res) {
      return res.data
    })
    .catch(function(res) {
       ...
    });
  }

});
```